# Method to export / import list of supported / excluded devices on Google Play Developer Console from one published application to a new application

Tags: android, device

I have a game published on the Google Play developer console (Game 1) and am about to publish another game (Game 2).

I would like to have Game 2 support and exclude the same devices as Game 1 without having to manually exclude devices again for Game 2 as this is a monotonous process.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have needed export the supported devices list in my app, and of course is a very monotonous job. So I have written an piece of code that parses the HTML and writes the device list on a new tab on a web browser.

With this, you can export it, but you can't import on another app, because Google doesn't allow it.

That's my code, I hope that can help someone.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].hasAttribute("data-manufacturer-group")){
        manufacturers.push(elements[i]);
    }
}

if(manufacturers.length > 0){
    for(var j=0; j<manufacturers.length; j++){
        for(var k=0; k<manufacturers[j].getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].getElementsByTagName("li").length; k++){
            var manufacturer = manufacturers[j].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML;
            var productIndex = manufacturers[j].getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[k].getElementsByTagName("span").length == 3 ? 1 : 0;
            var product = manufacturers[j].getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[k].getElementsByTagName("span")[productIndex].innerHTML;
            var nameIndex = manufacturers[j].getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[k].getElementsByTagName("span").length == 3 ? 2 : 1;
            var name = manufacturers[j].getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[k].getElementsByTagName("span")[nameIndex].innerHTML.substring(2);

            devices.push({"manufacturer": manufacturer, "product": product, "name": name});
        }
    }

    var text = "";
    for(var d=0; d<devices.length; d++){
        text += devices[d].manufacturer.trim() + " " + devices[d].product.trim() + " (" + devices[d].name.trim() + ")\n";
    }

    window.open("data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + escape(text));
}
```

I wrote a script and I use it on [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), a Google Chrome Extension.

If you want to see the complete code, is on my github repo. [GooglePlayDeviceListExporter](https://github.com/juliome10/GooglePlayDeviceExporter/)

Comment: Thank you. I got them now. :). Some one should accept this as answer.

Comment: Currently this solution is obsolete because Google changed Device Catalog.